# Nifi LookupAttribute processor with SimpleCsvFileLookupService doesn't work

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, lookup

I'd like to use a CSV file as a lookup table to update some attributes.

So I figured the *LookUpAttribute* processor was what I needed. I configured it with as *SimpleCsvFileLookupService* as the Lookup Service, but I can't get it to work yet.

My *SimpleCsvFileLookupService* is configured but stays in a "enabling" state, and the *LookUpAttribute* processor still tells me it's "invalid because performing validation depends on referencing a Controller Service that is currently disabled".

I dont understand why it doesn't enable. Has somebody used these components ? Thx

[image: Dataflow]
[image: LookAttribute properties]
[image: Controller services]

**Edit** :
I didn't see the message in the left. It says the mapping for "1" is not found ("1" is set as the lookup key column and in the csv the header row is "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8".

What am I missing ? I can't find any explanation as to how to use this controller service.

[image: Controller service warning]

**Edit2** : The SimpleCsvFileLookupService properties
[image: SimpleCsvFileLookupService properties]

**Edit3** : Extract of the csv file
[image: csv file]

Comment: Show SimpleCsvFileLookupService properties

Comment: @tonykoval I've added the properties screenshot

Comment: Can you also share an example (2 rows of csv) with the header?

Comment: It looks good. I tried with a similar CSV file (the exact header line) and the service works for me. Maybe there is some whitespace or encoding issue with your CSV file. I suggest renaming column names.

Comment: Indeed I just deleted and typed again the header line and it works now... I don't know exactly what was wrong, it's quite unnivering to lose time because of that kind of thing   Anyway thank you @tonykoval !

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Based on @tonykoval 's answer I checked the encoding of my csv file using the command `hexdump -C <filename>`.

The outcome of this command began with `00000000  ef bb bf`. `ef bb bf` signifies a bom character at the beginning of the file. To remove the bom from the file, I opened the file with vi `vi <filename>` and ran the command `:set nobomb`. I ran the hexdump command again and validated that I no longer had the bom.

Then I went back to nifi, disabled and enabled again my simpleCsvLookupService and it now validated as expected.